# phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner gives me an error when open it on android studio using ionic 6 an capacitor

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, barcode-scanner, capacitor

Could not find method compile() for arguments [{name=barcodescanner-release-2.1.5, ext=aar}] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

It should open android studio normally to build app but it gives me that error

here is my package.json

`

```
{
  "name": "test-barcode",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "https://ionicframework.com/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^14.0.0",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/barcode-scanner": "^6.2.0",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/core": "^6.2.0",
    "@capacitor/android": "4.5.0",
    "@capacitor/app": "4.1.0",
    "@capacitor/core": "4.5.0",
    "@capacitor/haptics": "4.0.1",
    "@capacitor/keyboard": "4.0.1",
    "@capacitor/status-bar": "4.0.1",
    "@ionic/angular": "^6.1.9",
    "ionicons": "^6.0.3",
    "phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner": "^8.1.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^14.0.0",
    "@capacitor/cli": "4.5.0",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^6.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "5.3.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "5.3.0",
    "eslint": "^7.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "30.7.6",
    "eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow": "1.2.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.3.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "typescript": "~4.7.2"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project"
}
```

`

and home-page.ts
`

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { BarcodeScanner } from '@awesome-cordova-plugins/barcode-scanner/ngx';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {

  content: any;

  constructor(private barcodeScanner: BarcodeScanner) {}


  barcode(){
    this.barcodeScanner.scan().then(barcodeData => {
      console.log('Barcode data', barcodeData);
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log('Error', err);
    });
  }

}
```

`

and this is build.gradle
`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "io.ionic.starter"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        aaptOptions {
             // Files and dirs to omit from the packaged assets dir, modified to accommodate modern web apps.
             // Default: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/282e181b58cf72b6ca770dc7ca5f91f135444502/tools/aapt/AaptAssets.cpp#61
            ignoreAssetsPattern '!.svn:!.git:!.ds_store:!*.scc:.*:!CVS:!thumbs.db:!picasa.ini:!*~'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    flatDir{
        dirs '../capacitor-cordova-android-plugins/src/main/libs', 'libs'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$androidxAppCompatVersion"
    implementation "androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:$androidxCoordinatorLayoutVersion"
    implementation "androidx.core:core-splashscreen:$coreSplashScreenVersion"
    implementation project(':capacitor-android')
    testImplementation "junit:junit:$junitVersion"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.ext:junit:$androidxJunitVersion"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:$androidxEspressoCoreVersion"
    implementation project(':capacitor-cordova-android-plugins')
}

apply from: 'capacitor.build.gradle'

try {
    def servicesJSON = file('google-services.json')
    if (servicesJSON.text) {
        apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    }
} catch(Exception e) {
    logger.info("google-services.json not found, google-services plugin not applied. Push Notifications won't work")
}
```

`

Answer (score 3):

I think you did everything correctly, I followed your steps and I managed to solve my issue, which was very similar to yours.

The error you are facing should be due to the fact that the plugin uses the old way of including native Android libraries by using `compile` instead of `implementation`.

The solution is well explained within this [post](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/error-when-i-build-with-phonegap-barcodescanner-ionic-native/218337/5), where the user Loiic says:

> You can change it manually (in Project Structure > Dependencies tab) the
> field “configuration” of the the dependency barcodescanner to switch
> from “compile” to “implementation”.

Make it a try and see if it works also for you .
Thank you.